# How do I change the path of a site in HTML, CSS, or JS?

Tags: html, css

How can I change the path of my site using HTML, CSS, or JS. I may be using the wrong grammar here using the word "path", but what I'm referring to is a subdomain, an example would be stackoverflow.com --> stackoverflow.com/questions

I attempted to use the element

```
<a href="about.html">
   <img src="x">
</a>
```

but it did not work,

Comment: The URL usually maps to a file structure, there's nothing you can do inside the JS/CSS/HTML that will control that (unless you are using a JS based SPA style routing system, but that seems unlikely from your question) Look at the structure of the files in your server/local file system.

Comment: I don't fully understand, what does structure of the files in my server/local file system refer to? Do you mean the order of them?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subdomain

Comment: I have read through your entire resource and not obtained the information I was looking for. I just need to click a button and have it redirect to another subdomain.

Comment: I guess you need `/` , use  `href="/about.html"` to go to `www.xyz.com/about.html`, or you need to read about how routing works.

Comment: @solar515 What exactly are you trying to do here? You want a link that takes you to another page?

Comment: @Karan Ghandhi Yes, I'm trying to click the image, and have it redirect me to a subdomain of the same page. The work I've done is using <a href="about.html"> with an image inside of the element.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You could think of a *server's public folder* (the one that host your site's static files as HTML, CSS, Js) as a directory in your computer. For you to redirect the user to another *path* in your site you can use as you said `<a href="[PATH]">Your link</a>` but keep in mind that if you want to go to another *folder* like `yoursite.com/anotherfolder` you must to have two things (for this example):

1. This folder structure in your site:

`[ROOTFOLDER]/anotherfolder/index.html`

In this case you need to add another file called `index.html` because is the default path that you get when no file is specified (file being specified: `yoursite.com/anotherfolder/file.html`).

2. The HTML anchor tag must to start with a slash like  `<a href="/anotherfolder/">Your link</a>`.

Hope it answer your question.

#### Note

You are talking about a *path* `http://yoursite.com/[PATH]`, a subdomain is like this `http://subdomain.yoursite.com`.